# React Native simulator cache

Tags: xcode, react-native

I've been having troubles with react native and running the simulator.
Specifically, I've added some native libraries to xcode, and made some modifications to them.
If I run from xcode on my device, or a simulator from xcode, everything is fine.
But when I run 'react-native run-ios', all changes I made inside xcode (native libraries, splash screen, etc.) don't reflect in the simulator.

I've tried this:
watchman watch-dell-all
npm cache clean
rm -rf ./node-modules && npm install
Tried run-ios with different --simulator options

Nothing seems to work.
I think the problem lies with the packager keeping cache, but where?
Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Which files were edited? Did you edit in Xcode or in node_modules? You can always update the packages.json to use the git repo/fork that had the fixes in stead of the original/buggy repo.